# Exclude closed HTML tags from string with regex

Tags: php, html, regex, special-characters

I've got a problem with the `preg_replace()` in PHP.

I get some unescaped HTML strings from a database and escape all special chars with `htmlentities()`. It worked good but it also replaces the `<` and `>`symbols, so I used `str_replace()` and replaced all the `&lt;` and  `&gt;`, so the tags are excluded from the replacement. All the tags I use are closed, but I use some contents that starts with `<` and `>` symbols like the string `&lt;nome programma&gt;` is seen like a tag.

So I decided to use `preg_replace()` with this regex `&lt;(\w+)&gt;(.*)&lt;\/(\w+)&gt;`

I have to escape those strings:

- `&lt;sub&gt;string&lt;/sub&gt;`
- `&lt;code&gt;start "&lt;nome programma&gt;":&lt;/code&gt;`
- `Il tipo &lt;code&gt;string&lt;/code&gt; e il tipo &lt;code&gt;char&lt;/code&gt;`

That works good for the first two cases, but not properly for the last one.

I've scratched an example [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jCK).

Can someone help me figuring out?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and `html_entity_decode` [sic]. Don't use regex for this!

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is too reductive...

`htmlentities()` replaces everything so I'm forced to use regex.

Comment: A, I see. So you got invalid HTML with content that looks like tags (that could even be or become tags), and you're trying to correct that using regex.. Those strings, by the way, are those the ones you got from the database? They seem to be escaped already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

The working regex is this one: `((&lt;)(\w+)(&gt;))(.*?)((&lt;)[\/+](\w+)(&gt;))`.

I Hope that this could help someone else!

Comment: Much simpler (and actually more accurate): `&lt;(\w+)&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/(\w+)&gt;`. Even better: `&lt;(\w+)&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/\1&gt;` (so that it only works with a matching closing tag).